# setting numerical hostname in Proxmox

Tags: hostname, domain-name, proxmox, fqdn

I am using Proxmox. I tried to run new OpenVZ container and I set my recently registered domain as a hostname in format "three digit number dot ie" (XXX.ie). The problem is, that after starting server, no matter what is written in files /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname the command

`hostname -f`

alway gives me answer just XXX (without dot ie). This way my domain is not FQDN and I'm having troubles with installation of any software.

I think it is Proxmox bug, because I tried to change hostname to, for example, to test.ie and it worked as it should.

I just querrying myself that maybe I should try set this domain name with quotation marks or any other trick which I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Problem sorted for me. Just changed distro to CentOS 6 and numerical hostname works fine. No clue, why it didn't work with Debian 7